# Match entries between two different tables on two different servers record-by-record

Tags: sql-server, netezza, informatica-powercenter

I have two different databases located on two different servers.

One is SQL Server while the other is Netezza.

I wish to check if the entries on the SQL Server are identical to the entries on my Netezza. I wish to do this record by record.

I want the output to tell me which entries exist in SQL Server but DO NOT exist in Netezza.

I am trying to use Informatica PowerCenter to create a mapping, but I am stumped.

Comment: How many rows of data in each table?

Comment: There seems to be two separate asks in your question... ask1) find records on SQL server which don't exist on Netezza... ask2) find records on SQL server which have same ID as on Netezza but rest of fields are not identical... please could you advise which  ask matches your requirements

Comment: If there is nothing identical in Netezza, I wish to return a NULL.

Comment: Each table could have around 100,000-500,000 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Joiner transformation to join those tables. Select Netezza table as Master and SQL server table as Detail and select the join type as Detail Outer Join.

Now in the output from joiner, you will get all rows from SQL server, and only matching rows from Netezza table. If the record is not present in Netezza, Netezza fields will come as NULL. You can check only one Netezza key field in an expression transformation afterwards to determine if the records is present in Netezza.

Comment: Good answer. If the amount of data is large you may have to increase memory in joiner or even sort the data (in a sorter trans or the database - it depends) and configure the joiner to take advantage of the sorted property.

Comment: Never add Sorter if the only reason is to use 'Sorted input' property on Joiner Transformation. You need to be very carefull here as Joiner expects BOTH pipelines sorted in this case. And adding a Sorter for both creates more cache than leaving it just up to the Joiner to cache the Master pipeline. This might be useful only in a case where e.g. Detail source can be read sorted (taking advantage of existing DB index) and you only need to sort the Master pipeline.

Comment: How do you put the connections for the separate servers? Also keep in mind that there are lots of tables, this cannot be for a single case.